# Where I am doing wrong in calculation in maximum total of subarray?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Hi I am trying to find the maximum total from the list. I don't understand where I am going wrong.

```
subarr = [8,-2,-4,-1] 

def sub(subarr):
    sum = 0
    m = max(subarr)
    for i in range(len(subarr)-1):
        for j in range(subarr[i+1],len(subarr)):
            sum = subarr[i] + subarr[j]
            if sum > m:
                m = sum
    return print(m)
sub(subarr)
```

Output:

```
16
```

Expected output:

```
8
```

Comment: can you define / elaborate on "maximum total"?

Comment: Like if 8 is a single element, then it is the highest. Else we will add two elements to check if the sum is highest or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```py
subarr = [8,-2,-4,-1] 

def sub(subarr):
    sum = 0
    m = max(subarr)
    for i in range(len(subarr)-1):
        sum = subarr[i]
        for j in range(i + 1,len(subarr)):
            sum += subarr[j]
            if sum > m:
                m = sum
    return print(m)
sub(subarr)
```

Comment: Oh, if you mean to only "add two elements", please only change line 8. Sorry, my english is not very well.